Unity editor crashes for no apparent reason
I am trying to open a unity project created on another PC (but with the same unity editor version).
After cloning the repo I try to open the project (with the same editor version) and unity will just crash without any message. Opening the project in safe mode doesn't show any errors in the logs.
This appears in the crash log file:
'''
...
[C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\LocalizationEditor\LocalizationDatabase.cpp:811]Packages/com.unity.learn.iet-framework/Editor/Localization/ja.po
[C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\LocalizationEditor\LocalizationDatabase.cpp:811]Packages/com.unity.timeline/Editor/Localization/ja.po
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit': dependency 'AddPassShader' shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit (Add Pass)' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit': dependency 'BaseMapShader' shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit (Base Pass)' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit': dependency 'BaseMapGenShader' shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit (Basemap Gen)' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Particles/Unlit': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Shader Graphs/PhysicalMaterial3DsMax': fallback shader 'Hidden/Shader Graph/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Nature/SpeedTree8': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Shader Graphs/InteractablePrimitive': fallback shader 'Hidden/Shader Graph/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Autodesk Interactive/AutodeskInteractiveMasked': fallback shader 'Hidden/Shader Graph/FallbackError' not found
Shader Hidden/ProbeVolume/VoxelizeScene is not supported: GPU does not support conservative rasterization
Shader 'Shader Graphs/PhysicalMaterial3DsMaxTransparent': fallback shader 'Hidden/Shader Graph/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit (Add Pass)': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Baked Lit': fallback shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Unlit' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Lit': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/VR/SpatialMapping/Occlusion': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Nature/SpeedTree7': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Nature/SpeedTree7': dependency 'BillboardShader' shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Nature/SpeedTree7 Billboard' not found
Shader 'Universal Render Pipeline/Nature/SpeedTree7 Billboard': fallback shader 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' not found
Shader Hidden/ProbeVolume/VoxelizeScene is not supported: GPU does not support conservative rasterization
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.10 seconds
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.09 seconds
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.11 seconds
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.15 seconds
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.13 seconds
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.18 seconds
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.33 seconds
Crash!!!
...
'''

Have you tried to ask Unity support?

I encountered a similar problem, which happened when I switched project's build profile from Windows to Android (URP with 2D Renderer setup). Updating my AMD GPU drivers via https://www.amd.com/en/support/download/drivers.html resolved the crashing problem.
